# How can I implement some sort of alarm clock functionality for a Python program running on raspbmc?

Tags: python, debian, raspberry-pi, xbmc

I'm turning my raspberry pi running on raspbmc (based on Debian) into an alarm clock that turns my tv on, displays the weather and plays a predifined song at, you guessed it, a specific time. I currently have most of the functionality implemented with Python e.g.: storing the path to a file for the song and filling in the wake-up time via a simple web interface.

I'm wondering what the best way (least intensive) is to run the wake-up routine at a specific time entered by me and, of course, change it when a new time is entered.

Hope you guys can help me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set up a cron task and set up a python script to perform the actions you need when triggered by cron.

Try:

```
% crontab -e
```

add a line:

```
10 7 * * 1-5 /path/to/your/script
```

Save & exit.

This should run your script at 7:10 Monday-Friday